# Is there a gcloud command that can be used to list all APIs in use across your GCP organisation?

Tags: google-cloud-platform

I understand that you can check API usage from within a project but I'd like a high-level overview of all projects where a particular API is enabled - is there a simple command for this?

Answer (score 0):

The API's are listed by project, it cannot be listed by organization, since it depends on what services are being used on the different projects.

To list the enabled [services in the project](https://cloud.google.com/service-usage/docs/list-services#enabled), you can run the following [command](https://cloud.google.com/sdk/gcloud/reference/beta/services/list):

gcloud services list

To list it across the organization, you can maybe create an script that list it on any project and separate them on different lists to have them organized by project.

To do it by project you can use the same command but using the flag to define a project:

gcloud services list --project